# How to solve group by error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table storing the information about all employees and i need to calculate the percentage of females.
this is my query but it is giving me the following error : not a single-group group function

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE)
 FROM EMPLOYEE E
 WHERE E.GENDER='F';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to scan the table twice:

```
select count(case Gender when 'F' then 1 else null end) / count(*)
from Employee;

select count(decode(Gender, 'F', 1, null)) / count(*)
from Employee;

select (count(*) - count(nullif(Gender, 'F'))) / count(*)
from Employee; -- Only works if Gender is not null

select avg(decode(Gender, 'F', 1, 0))
from Employee
```